# $M=(0,1) \times \{0\}$ is not an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\rho$ denote the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction, $M$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\forall x \in M$, $\exists \ r>0$ s.t. $B_r(x) \subset M$.

Pick a point $a=\left<\frac{1}{2}, \frac{r}{2} \right> \in \mathbb{R}^2$
and a point $b=\left<\frac{1}{2}, 0 \right> \in M$

$\rho(a,b)=\frac{r}{2} \lt r \implies a \in B_r(b)$

Since $M$ is an open set by hypothesis, then $B_r(b) \subset M \implies a \in M$ which is a contradiction since the $y$ component is non-zero. Hence, $M$ is not closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to do it directly: Fix $a=(x,0)\in M$ and let $B_r((x,0))$ be an open ball of radius $r$ about $a$, in $\mathbb R^2.$ Then, $(x,r/2)\in B_r((x,0))\setminus M$, so $M$ can not be open.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine except for the sentence 'Then $\exists r>0$ s.t. $\forall$  $x \in M$ $B_x(r) \subset M$'.  This is wrong. You should say:  $\forall$  $x \in M$ $\exists r>0$ s.t.  $B_x(r) \subset M$. [$r$ may depend on $x$].

Comment: Makes sense. I have edited the proof accordingly.